# ASP.Net: What's keeping old AppDomains alive?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, signalr

We're having quite a problem with our newly redesigned website - old AppDomains never die.

We upload new versions manually (copying files to a new folder on the website) and then just switch the home directory.

This causes all new requests to hit the new code.

Now before our redesign the old AppDomain would die out pretty fast (usually a few seconds)

Not so any longer however, now the AppDomains stay alive forever (or until an application pool recycle is forced). This is quite a problem as it eats a lot of memory, and who knows what it's doing behind the scenes...

The major new parts in our redesign is the usage of SignalR for an instant messenger-like chat, as well as a persistent WCF connection to a backplane for SignalR (homebrewed)

SignalR will use Websockets when available clientside, as we run IIS 8 with Websocket support enabled.

I've tried disabling both the SignalR script, and the WCF connection, and the AppDomains still won't die.

Is there any logs or similar which could help me figure out why the AppDomains stay alive?
Could a memory dump show something?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  Running into the same issue myself. We do use signalr, but I can never reproduce on a development machine.

Comment: Unforuntately no I never figured this thing out, we're still having the issue and are currently forcing app pool recycle whenever we upload. This shuts down all AppDomains. If you find the solution I'd love to know it, and likewise I'll post here if I ever find one.

Comment: Our issue turned out to be unrelated to signalr.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25570185/asp-net-web-application-doesnt-unload-appdomains-after-deploy?noredirect=1#comment40114062_25570185